# Rewritten htaccess URL being cleared by hash

Tags: html, .htaccess

I have a page with a RewriteRule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/$ index.php?user=$1&language=$2 [QSA,L]
```

In the index.php page, I have several links pointing to hashes # of element ids. When the user lands on the page, he gets this nice looking url:

```
mydomain.com/username/en
```

Which points to

```
mydomain.com/index.php?user=username&language=en
```

The problem is, as soon as one of the links is clicked, the browser changes the url to

```
mydomain.com/#id
```

Isn't it supposed to change to something like this?

```
mydomain.com/username/en#id
```

I want my url to look like the one above, that seems to be the expected behavior of the page...

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind... just found the problem

I was using JS to push history states and it ended up messing with the urls!

Comment: I'm willing to do, it's just that I have to wait 2 days hehe